# Load an svg object on click instead of loading with the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, object, svg, onclick, loading

I have a page that open's divs containing svgs embedded using the object tab when a certain a link is clicked, but the svg objects are loaded when the page loads which is going to make the page load very slowly if all the svgs load even though they aren't displayed. I need a javascript function that will cause the svg object to load on click and not to load until then.

I was hesitant in making a new question for this because it seems so simple that I should have been able to find the answer elsewhere. But all the answers to similar questions seem to explain how to show and hide the svg in a div, which is what I already have. I need to delay the loading of the src until a certain onclick event.

Comment: Do you have embedded svg like the  

    <svg /> 

tag or do you use  

    <img /> <embed /> <object />

This could change some factors?

Comment: <object type="image/svg+xml" data="url"></object>